# OS X Power PC RE tool (debugger/disassembler)

Tags: ida, debuggers, osx, disassemblers

So I want to know is such tool exist without counting IDA PRO. And is there any GUI version of it if exist - because I really don't want to debugging with terminal. My OS X version is Snow Leopard. I want to disassemble and debug an PowerPC app which runs with Rosetta on OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it myself but I've heard about **otx** (object tool extended):

> otx stands for "object tool extended". It uses otool (object tool) to
>   disassemble a Mach-O executable file, then enhances the disassembled
>   output. Simple enhancements include adding the machine code of each
>   instruction and the offset of each instruction from the beginning of a
>   function. More complicated enhancements include displaying the names
>   and data types of Objective-C methods even if symbols have been
>   stripped, and adding comments that describe member variables, function
>   calls, static data and more.

http://otx.osxninja.com/

Comment: Thank you but I have already seen this tool and I don't find it useful because it isn't have a debugger.

Comment: You need to be more specific then, your question doesn't state that the tool *has to* have a debugger.